# MySQL query runs slower when repeated

Tags: mysql, geolocation, query-performance

The following query (which I didn't write) does a search based on distance calculations in a 50,000-record table.  The first time I run it (in phpMyAdmin), it runs in under 0.25 seconds.  If I immediately run it again, it takes over 30 seconds.  I tried adding `SQL_NO_CACHE` but it made no difference.  Since in production the same query could be run multiple times in short order, this is a major concern.

Note that if the user selects additional criteria (keywords) on the search page, which require joined tables in which string searches are done, the problem goes away;  I'm assuming that the text searches are done first, leaving fewer distance calculations.  (This is why there is a GROUP BY on the primary key; these extended searches can produce multiple instances of the PK.)

Also note that on my local test system, the query runs in under 0.02 seconds no matter how many times I rerun it.

Here's the query (a sample generated from the actual search page):

```
SELECT 
    `cc6177_clients`.*,
    ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(`b1e39c_client_lat`)) * SIN(RADIANS(51.0486151)) + COS(RADIANS(`b1e39c_client_lat`)) * COS(RADIANS(51.0486151)) * COS(RADIANS(`b1e39c_client_long`) - RADIANS(- 114.0708459))) * 3964
          AS `distance`
FROM
    `cc6177_clients`
WHERE
    (b1e39c_client_status = '1'
        AND b1e39c_client_profile_status = '1'
        AND b1e39c_client_type = 'provider')
GROUP BY `b1e39c_client_id`
HAVING (distance <= 50)
ORDER BY `b1e39c_client_company_name` ASC
LIMIT 8
```

Here's the EXPLAIN output:

```
1   SIMPLE  cc6177_clients  ref PRIMARY,client_email,client_company_name,main_search    main_search 3   const,const,const   26564   Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
```

And here's the CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `cc6177_clients` (
 `b1e39c_client_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `b1e39c_client_type` enum('client','provider') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_login_type` enum('normal','social') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'normal',
 `b1e39c_client_oauth_provider` enum('facebook','gplus') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_oauth_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_access_token` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `b1e39c_client_referrer_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_nickname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_picture` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_country_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_contact_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_lat` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_long` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_state` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_postal_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_status` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0=>Not Active,1=>Active',
 `b1e39c_client_activation_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'It is used for account activation or reset password request key',
 `b1e39c_client_verified` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'It is used to verify client email address(0=>not Verified,1=>Verified)',
 `b1e39c_client_registered_on` datetime NOT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_login_failed_count` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_login_failed_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_login_ip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_view_status` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_delete_status` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0=>client deleted, 1=> client active',
 `b1e39c_client_verify_email_link_exp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_company_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_website_address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_company_logo` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Provider Company Logo',
 `b1e39c_client_desc` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `b1e39c_client_category_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_sub_category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `b1e39c_client_claim_option` enum('0','1','2') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=>default,1=>User Added By Admin,2=>claim then make main provider',
 `b1e39c_client_membership_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'client current membership table unique id',
 `b1e39c_client_cur_membership_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'client currency membership',
 `b1e39c_client_membership_type` enum('free','paid') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'client membership type',
 `b1e39c_client_profile_status` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `b1e39c_client_profile_cover` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`b1e39c_client_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `client_email` (`b1e39c_client_email`),
 KEY `client_company_name` (`b1e39c_client_company_name`),
 KEY `main_search` (`b1e39c_client_status`,`b1e39c_client_profile_status`,`b1e39c_client_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=55931 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Have you try to troubleshoot this using EXPLAIN?

Comment: A `show create table cc6177_clients`  dump might be helpful to answer your question - and the server version `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: About the "the user selects additional criteria". How?

Comment: You have not given us enough information to help you. Please read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/  Pay special attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: `GROUP BY b1e39c_client_id` - Are you grouping by the primary key? It makes no sense.

Comment: Good point, grouping on a PK for 1 table would be rather pointless.  To be honest, I'm a bit intrigued by the naming of those fields: `b1e39c_...`. Why would one need to prefix the fieldnames like that? Unless it has multiple versions of the `..._client_id` etc. in that table?  I got a hunch that it's not the PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `VARCHAR(255)` everywhere; use reasonable limits.  (This will help with the performance of the temp tables that are currently needed.

Use a "bounding box" in the `WHERE` clause, plus `INDEX(lat), INDEX(long)`.  (See below.)

Don't clutter the SQL with a constant prefix (`b1e39c_client_`).  (A Human thing.)

Get rid of `GROUP BY`; it adds nothing to *this* query other than slowing it down.  (This eliminates an unnecessary pass over the data.)

None of those can explain why the first run was significantly faster than the next run.

A "bounding box" is something like

```
 AND lat  BETWEEN .. AND ..
 AND long BETWEEN .. AND ..
```

with the values filled in to be 50 units away from the source lat/long.  (Note that you need to divide by cosd(lat) for the `long` tests.)

This will speed up the query by an order of magnitude, thereby making it so fast that your original question becomes moot.

Without the bounding box, this might help:

```
INDEX(status, profile_status, type,   -- in any order
      company_name)   -- last
```

If you want to pursue the original question, see if you can get `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to show two different outputs.

Comment: The constant prefix and everything being varchar(255) were there when I inherited the project, unfortunately, but I hope to clean up as much as I can.